# Update Entity with One to Many relationship

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am running into problem where there is one-to-many relationship and I am trying to update the data in one of the tables and the link table.

- I have two tables (User, Roles) and one link table (UserRoles).
- A User has many Roles.
- The Roles are predefined and there are only 3 rows as shown below.

I want to update the User with Roles. I am unable to do with the following code.
Please share your inputs.

```
Original
User : John
Roles : Admin, User

Update to
User : John
Roles : User
```

This is the table structure

```
User
UserID : Pk
Name

Roles //Data is not added in this table, Data already exists in this table
RoleID : Pk
Name

RoleID   Name
1        Admin
2        User
3        None

UserRoles
UserID  : PK
RoleID : Pk
```

The corresponding **entities**

```
User
UserId
Name
EntityCollection<Role> Roles

Role
RoleId
Name
EntityCollection<User> Users
```

I have tried with following code

```
public void update(int userId, string newusername, list<int> roleList)
{
    using (DBEntites context = new DBEntites())
    {
        User objUserInDb = new User();
        objUserInDb.UserID = userId;
        Context.Users.Attach(objUserInDb);
        objUserInDb.Name = newusername;
        objUserInDb.Roles.Clear(); 

        // TRIED TO USE The remove method objUserInDb.Roles.Remove(entity), 
        // is returning false

        foreach (long pkIDToAdd in roleList)
        {
            Role objRoleInDb = new Role();
            objRoleInDb.RoleId = pkIDToAdd;

            // GIVES EXCEPTION 
            //An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. 
            //The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same    
            //
            context.Roles.Attach(objRoleInDb);
            objUserInDb.Roles.Add(objRoleInDb);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception is because some roles are loaded to the context already. You can do like this,

```
  foreach (long pkIDToAdd in roleList)
        {
            var role=  context.RiskTypes.FirstOrDefault(r=>r.id==pkIDToAdd );
            objUserInDb.Roles.Add(role);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, Jayantha. Actually i am trying to avoid a database call by using the FirstOrDefault method and hence using the Attach method. I have tried with the TryGetObjectByKey method with the newly created RiskType using Role objRole = new Role(); objRole.RoleId = 1; but i can see that the Entity key for the objRole is null and EntityState is detached. when i try to use the Attach method it gives exception of object with key exists already. I want to avoid using the hardcoded string to create a new entity key and themn check for it. Hope i am clear

Comment: Yes I got it.You can check  `context.Entry(role).State` and if it is `Detached`  you can attach it again.